# Why ngClass is failing in a case where the evaluated property is repeated in the following case?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ng-class

I made a reusable input in the form of a component, I used ngClass to set different backgrounds. and it works well in 4 out of 5 scenarios. There's a case where the evaluated variable named "estados" is equal to "pagado", but it won't apply its corresponding class. I can't figure out why.

HTML:

```
<ion-item  lines="none" class="chipEstados"
[ngClass]="{colorEvaluacion: estado === 'enEvaluacion', colorAprobado: estado === 'aprobado', colorPagado: estado === 'pagado', colorPagado: estado === 'aprobadoParcial', colorRechazado: estado === 'rechazado'}">
  <ion-icon name="time" class="iconEvaluacion"></ion-icon> //modificar el name tambien
  <ion-label class="chipTexto">{{texto}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

SASS:

```
.iconEvaluacion {
    color: #F39837;
}

.colorEvaluacion {
    --background: #FDF6E9;
}

.iconAprobado {
    color: #329CDA;
}

.colorAprobado {
    --background: #ECF5FF;
}

.iconPagado {
    color: #78A856;
}

.colorPagado {
    --background: #E9F8E6;
}

.iconRechazado {
    color: #EC3F5A;
}

.colorRechazado {
    --background: #FFEDED;
}
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chip-estados',
  templateUrl: './chip-estados.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chip-estados.component.scss'],
})
export class ChipEstadosComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() estado: string;
  @Input() texto: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

And this is the parent's HTML where I'm calling it and passing the via data-binding the different "estados" properties from parent to child.

```
  <app-chip-estados texto="En Evaluación" estado="enEvaluacion"></app-chip-estados>
  <app-chip-estados texto="Aprobado" estado="aprobado"></app-chip-estados>
  <app-chip-estados texto="Pagado" estado="pagado"></app-chip-estados>
  <app-chip-estados texto="Aprobado Parcial" estado="aprobadoParcial"></app-chip-estados>
  <app-chip-estados texto="Rechazado" estado="rechazado"></app-chip-estados>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I made a reusable input in the form of a component, I used ngClass to set different backgrounds. and it works well in 4 out of 5 scenarios. There's a case where the evaluated variable named "estados" is equal to "pagado", but it won't apply its corresponding class. I can't figure out why.

The reason is below value within `[ngClass]` binding:

```html
colorPagado: estado === 'pagado', colorPagado: estado === 'aprobadoParcial'
```

When "estados" is equal to "pagado", `colorPagado: estado === 'pagado'` condition results in the class being added, but `colorPagado: estado === 'aprobadoParcial'` condition evaluates to `false` and thereby results in removing the same class `colorPagado`.

If you want to apply the same class when "estados" is equal to "pagado" or "aprobadoParcial", then you can modify the expression as:

```html
colorPagado: (estado === 'pagado' || estado === 'aprobadoParcial')
```